# Stage3D: Camera pans the whole screen

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, camera, matrix, stage3d

I am trying to create a 2D Stage3D game where you can move the camera around the level in an RTS style. I thought about using Orthographic Matrix3D functions for this but when I try to scroll the whole "stage" also scrolls.

This is the Camera code:

```
    public function Camera2D(width:int, height:int, zoom:Number = 1) {
        resize(width, height);
                    _zoom = zoom;
    }

    public function resize(width:Number, height:Number):void {
        _width = width;
        _height = height;

        _projectionMatrix = makeMatrix(0, width, 0, height);

        _recalculate = true;
    }

    protected function makeMatrix(left:Number, right:Number, top:Number, bottom:Number, zNear:Number = 0, zFar:Number = 1):Matrix3D {
        return new Matrix3D(Vector.<Number>([
            2 / (right - left), 0, 0, 0,
            0, 2 / (top - bottom), 0, 0,
            0, 0, 1 / (zFar - zNear), 0,
            0, 0, zNear / (zNear - zFar), 1
        ]));
    }

    public function get viewMatrix():Matrix3D {
        if (_recalculate) {
            _recalculate = false;

            _viewMatrix.identity();
            _viewMatrix.appendTranslation( -_width / 2 - _x, -_height / 2 - y, 0);
            _viewMatrix.appendScale(_zoom, _zoom, 1);

            _renderMatrix.identity();
            _renderMatrix.append(_viewMatrix);

            _renderMatrix.append(_projectionMatrix);
        }

        return _renderMatrix;
    }
```

And the camera is send directly to the GPU with: `c3d.setProgramConstantsFromMatrix(Context3DProgramType.VERTEX, 0, cameraMatrix, true);`

And these are the shaders:

```
------Vertex Shader------
m44 op, va0, vc0
mov v0, va1.xy
mov v0.z, va0.z

------Fragment Shader------
tex ft0, v0, fs0 <2d,linear,nomip>
mov oc, ft1
```

---

Here is a [example](http://www.newgrounds.com/dump/item/70405221c75141c1386230eebfd2938f) and here are two screenshots to show what I mean: [image: Frame 1][image: Frame 2]

How do I only let the inside of the stage3D scroll and not the whole stage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already figured it out, the problem was in the fact that I had different passes for the shaders.

So my shader logic was like this:

1. Draw Stage to Texture as normal and as diffuse map
2. Draw the Texture to the Stage

And for both passes I used the same transformation `Matrix3D`, so when the Stage was panned the texture that the whole Stage was drawn on was also panned.
The solution is that all I had to do was create a simple `Matrix3D` object for drawing the Textures to the Stage, because the positions of the Texture should never change.